# Create timestamp of now as NSNumber in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, timestamp

How can I get timestamp as `NSNumber`? I only need something like this: `1232885280`

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
// NSTimeInterval is defined as double
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
```

Comment: it is returning this, Printing description of timeStampObj:
1503391732.631865

Answer (score 0):

**Time Intervals Since 1970**

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

**Time Intervals Since Now**

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

**Time Intervals Since Date**

```
NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
comps.year = 2014;
comps.month = 3;
comps.day = 31;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* date = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
```

**Time Intervals Since Reference Date**

The Intervals between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 january 2001.

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```